# mysql binding to the parent child relationship query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which works well if thhe level is only 1 level deep, but if there are more levels, the query is causing trouble as it does not show the nested levels

```
SELECT
    question.question,
    answer.answer,
    answer.questionid,
    answer.pid, 
    question.DateAdded,
    answer.DateAdded 
    FROM
    answer
    RIGHT JOIN question ON answer.questionid = question.id
```

please guide as how i ca approach

my table structure is like this:

question table:

```
id
question 
DateAdded
```

answers table:

```
pid
answer
questionid
DateAdded
```

by Nested level means that entry will be inserted in the answers table using the `pid` of the answers table and inserted into the `questionid` field

Comment: As I can understand your `pid` is referencing `quiestionid` field. So you have an answer tree structure. So you probably want to display this tree structure somewhere. Am I right?

Comment: yes, i am doing it in a select box, but when i had made an entry how do i display it. because as of now, i am using ul >li structure

Comment: I'm afraid you will not be able to get all information in a single query. This will require you to add new `join` to enable every new layer. That is what you might be thinking about. Forget.

Comment: What you may need is consequent recursive queries.

Comment: So you are doing web-development as I can see. What server language are you using?

Comment: I assume you should have an `id` field in `answer` table. So `pid` field should be referencing `id` field, shouldn't it?

Comment: using coldfusion as front end and mysql as backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following html markup with pseudo code server-language.

```
Question:<br/>
{{question.question}}<br/>

Answers:<br/>
<ul>
{{foreach answer in getRootAnswers(question.id)}}
    <li>{{printAnswer(answer)}}</li>
{{/foreach}}
</ul>
```

`getRootAnswers(questionId)` function will return a top-level answer where `pid` is null. It should generate a query like

```
SELECT
    answer,
    id,
    DateAdded 
    FROM answer
    WHERE questionid = @questionId AND pid is null
    ORDER BY DateAdded
```

`printAnswer` will be generating a markup

```
Added on: {{answer.DateAdded}}<br/>
{{answer.answer}}<br/>
<ul>
{{foreach childAnswer in getChildAnswers(answer.id)}}
    <li>{{printAnswer(childAnswer)}}</li>
{{/foreach}}
<ul>
```

The markup will first print `answer` information. Then it will print child answers of the `answer`. Notice `printAnswer` recursive call.

`getChildAnswers(parentId)` function will return a child answers where of the answer identified by `parentId`. It should generate a query like

```
SELECT
    answer,
    id,
    DateAdded 
    FROM answer
    WHERE pid = @parentId
    ORDER BY DateAdded
```

You end up having a single query for every node in the answer tree.